# Error when installing tensorflow in specific folder

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, pip, h5py

I am trying to install TensorFlow (mac M1).

To do the installation, I first set up a virtual environment and then do the pip installation. However, while this works perfectly fine in my home directory, I can not do it at a different place, such as a folder in my Documents catalog.

The commands I am doing are the following:

```
/usr/bin/python3 -m venv env
source env/bin/activate 
pip install tensorflow-macos
```

As I said, it works fine in the home catalog, but not in a specific folder.

The error I am getting when doing it in a specific folder:

```
Building h5py requires pkg-config unless the HDF5 path is explicitly specified
  error: pkg-config probably not installed: FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
```

I have checked that the python versions are the same, as well as pip. But still no success. I have also tried reinstalling NumPy, PEP515, p5py, and wheel. Also tried uninstalling TensorFlow in the home catalog before installing it somewhere else.

Comment: Have you checked user rights ? can you normally write on that path ?

Comment: `brew install pkg-config` or `brew install hdf5` and `export HDF5_DIR=$(brew --cellar hdf5)`

Comment: if you're using an m1 mac you need to instal via brew, then export as `export HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5@1.8` then pip will install. See issue here: https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/1800